# How to fix discord buttons "this interaction failed error" in my script (python)

Tags: python, button, discord, bots

```
@bot.command()
async def coin(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send(
        "This is our **bet** coin : <:coiner:902807543569584158>",
        components = [
            Button(label = "Animated coin")
        ]
    )
    while True:
        interaction = await bot.wait_for("button_click", check = lambda i: i.component.label.startswith("Animated"))
        await interaction.respond(content = "<a:coinanimated:9028075435695848902>")
```

When I open discord and try to press button, it will write "this interaction failed" error

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: i solved it already, thanks for repeating

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

`pip uninstall discord.py`

`pip install discord.py=1.7.3`

Then just use same code